# Replacing templates according to events from Navbar in Angular 2

Tags: angular, navbar

I've got this navbar at the top like in most other UIs. Here, what I'd like to do is replace the content of the following *div* according to the tabs clicked in the navbar. I'm not totally changing the routes here. I'm still in the same route but I'd like the templates changed.

I searched about it and couldn't find a satisfying way of doing it. Since I'm new to the entire angular platform, I have really less idea about how this is done. Any help or idea would be great.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<component-a></component-a> //this is a component selector
```

I'd like to have multiple other component's template shown inside the component-a selector, somewhat like:

```
<component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
</component-a> //either this

<component-a>
        <component-c></component-c>
</component-a> //or this
```

or even the combination of both.

Comment: You can use [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) to conditionally add/remove elements from the DOM.. what exactly are you trying to do? Can you share a code example?

Comment: You wants to just change html content Or entire component?

Comment: I've changed the question a bit. Maybe that'll give you some idea.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **hidden** property in this case to **show/hide** child component/div as per requirement as below. You can also use ***ngIf** condition.

However hidden is more preferable because it will not render hidden component constructor and other initial calls

```
//change your logic in hidden properties, you can also put same logic for other component too.
<component-a >
   <component-b [hidden]="1==1"></component-b>
   <component-c [hidden]="1==2"></component-c>
</component-a>
```

Comment: this one is obviously better than using ElementRef and replacing the entire content of the main component selector. However, I'd like to know if this is the only way to do it. I mean if there were other alternatives, I could probably compare and analyse. But this seems to do the trick as well. Thanks!

Comment: your concern is about just render inner html of main component, so by above method is more suitable. If your requirement for render entire new component then dynamic component load will require.